# Qt 6.2.4 deployed application with MinGW don't run on Win 7 64:

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, entry-point

Entry point not found (api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll)

I have already tried to install vc redistributable and move the dll to the application folder.
The strange thing is that the dll is present in the Windows folders it is not missing.

Comment: Check if application is 32-bit or 64-bit. In case of 32-bit the fact that you find the DLL in the Windows folder doesn't mean it's the right one...

Comment: The application is 64-bit, but i think i found the problem [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/supported-platforms.html)